# I want to target an html attribute with JS and make it equal to 0.

Tags: javascript, html

How to target an html attribute with JS by his id and make it equal to some number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById('foo').setAttribute('bar', 0);`

Where `foo` is the ID of your element and `bar` is the name of the attribute you want to change.

Comment: I think i didn't explain myself right. I want to target an ID and set his value to some number.
something like: document.getElementById('foo') = 0; but in a proper way.

Comment: So you want to change an element's ID to the number 0? That's a bad idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

However, you could change its id much the same way I posted above to a safe name including the number zero.

`document.getElementById('foo').setAttribute('id', 'element-0');`